# Raspberry Pi to Unity: Moving an object based on UDP data

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, udp

I have linked up a Raspberry Pi to Unity and am receiving the data in the form of a string "xxx yyy" where xxx is a 3 digit x position and yyy is a 3 digit y position. I am currently getting the information from the raspberry pi to write to the Unity Console, but my code isn't properly reading that information from the console. How do I fix this? Here are the two scripts relating to this issue:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MoveBox : MonoBehaviour {

    //string data;
    string[] split_data;
    int x;
    int y;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {


    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        string data = Console.ReadLine ();


        split_data = data.Split(' ');
        x = Int32.Parse(split_data [0]);
        y = Int32.Parse(split_data [1]);
        transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, 0);


    }
}
```

and

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

public class UDPRecieve : MonoBehaviour {

    /*

    -----------------------
    UDP-Receive (send to)
    -----------------------
    // [url]http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb979228.aspx#ID0E3BAC[/url]


    // > receive
    // 128.235.117.235 : 8051

    // send
    // nc -u 128.235.117.235 8051

*/
        // receiving Thread
        Thread receiveThread;

        // udpclient object
        UdpClient client;

        // public
        // public string IP = "128.235.117.235"; default local
        public int port; // define > init

        public static GameObject cube;


        // infos
        public string lastReceivedUDPPacket="";
        public string allReceivedUDPPackets=""; // clean up this from time to time!

        private string info;
        public static int x;
        public static int y;
        private string[] arraySplit; 



        // start from shell
        private static void Main()
        //public void Update()
        {


            UDPRecieve receiveObj=new UDPRecieve();
            receiveObj.init();

            string text="";
            do
            {
                text = Console.ReadLine();
                cube.transform.position = new Vector3 (x, y, 0);
            }
            while(!text.Equals("exit"));


        }
        // start from unity3d
        public void Start()
        {

            init();  

            cube = GameObject.Find ("Cube");
        }

        // OnGUI
        void OnGUI()
        {
            Rect rectObj=new Rect(40,10,200,400);
            GUIStyle style = new GUIStyle();
            style.alignment = TextAnchor.UpperLeft;
            GUI.Box(rectObj,"# UDPReceive\n128.235.117.235 "+port+" #\n"
                    + "shell> nc -u 128.235.117.235 : "+port+" \n"
                    + "\nLast Packet: \n"+ lastReceivedUDPPacket
                    + "\n\nAll Messages: \n"+allReceivedUDPPackets
                    ,style);
        }

        // init
        private void init()
        {
            // Endpunkt definieren, von dem die Nachrichten gesendet werden.
            print("UDPSend.init()");

            // define port
            port = 6666;  

            // status
            print("Sending to 128.235.117.235 : "+port);
            print("Test-Sending to this Port: nc -u 128.235.117.235  "+port+"");


            // ----------------------------
            // Abhören
            // ----------------------------
            // Lokalen Endpunkt definieren (wo Nachrichten empfangen werden).
            // Einen neuen Thread für den Empfang eingehender Nachrichten erstellen.
            receiveThread = new Thread(
                new ThreadStart(ReceiveData));
            receiveThread.IsBackground = true;
            receiveThread.Start();

        }

        // receive thread
        private  void ReceiveData()
        {

            client = new UdpClient(port);
            while (true)
            {

                try
                {
                    // Bytes empfangen.
                    IPEndPoint anyIP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
                    byte[] data = client.Receive(ref anyIP);

                    // Bytes mit der UTF8-Kodierung in das Textformat kodieren.
                    string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);

                    arraySplit = text.Split(' ');
                    x = Int32.Parse(arraySplit [0]);
                    y = Int32.Parse(arraySplit [1]);
                    //this.transform.position = new Vector3 (x, y, 0);

                    // Den abgerufenen Text anzeigen.
                    print(">> " + text);

                    // latest UDPpacket
                    lastReceivedUDPPacket=text;

                    // ....
                    allReceivedUDPPackets=allReceivedUDPPackets+text;

                }
                catch (Exception err)
                {
                    print(err.ToString());
                }
            }
        }

        // getLatestUDPPacket
        // cleans up the rest
        public string getLatestUDPPacket()
        {
            allReceivedUDPPackets="";
            return lastReceivedUDPPacket;
        }
    /*
        public void UseInfo()
        {
            info = lastReceivedUDPPacket;
            arraySplit = info.Split ('0');
            x =  int.Parse(arraySplit [0]);
            y =  int.Parse(arraySplit [1]);
            this.transform.position = new Vector3 (x, y, 0);

        } */

    void OnDisable() 
    { 
        if ( receiveThread!= null) 
            receiveThread.Abort(); 

        client.Close(); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Ok so I realize the first problem is I am not writing and reading to the same place, so now I have been using task delegation. However, when I try to delegate a task in the main thread of the UDPRevieve script, I get an error that states I have to have an object reference to use a static property or something like that.

Comment: Are [you guys working together](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31614594/unity-threading-issue-not-able-to-delegate-task)? If so, you may want to come up with a single question clearly stating the issues you encounter and demonstrating where in your code this happens.

Comment: We are working together. Thank you for the advice. As of now, we are facing the error: TrySetSetString can only be called from the main thread.
Constructors and field initializers will be executed from the loading thread when loading a scene.
Don't use this function in the constructor or field initializers, instead move initialization code to the Awake or Start function. However, all of our variables are initialized inside of Start() or another function.