# Unity Threading Issue: Not able to delegate task

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine

I am using a raspberry pi to send information to Unity via UDP. In order to circumvent the multi-threading issue with Unity, I am delegating a task in a part of the script. I am getting an error stating:

"error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member `UDPReceive.te'"

How can I properly send the information using this task delegation technique? I have the raspberry pi sending information properly to Unity but am unable to retrieve the information due to the threading issue, which is what I am trying to work around here.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

public class UDPReceive : MonoBehaviour {

    // receiving Thread
    Thread receiveThread;

    // udpclient object
    UdpClient client;

    // public
    public string IP = "128.235.117.210";
    public int port; // define > init
    public TaskExecutorScript te;


    // NEW
    public int X;
    public int Y;
    string[] split_data;
    public static GameObject cube;



    // infos
    public string lastReceivedUDPPacket="";

    private string info;

    // start from shell
    private static void Main()
        //public void Update()
    {


        UDPReceive receiveObj=new UDPReceive();
        receiveObj.init();

        string text="";
        do
        {
            text = Console.ReadLine();

        }
        while(!text.Equals("exit"));



        // NEW
        te.ScheduleTask(new Task(delegate
                                                 {
            // Add whatever Unity API code you want here
            //split_data = text.Split(' ');
            //X = Int32.Parse(split_data [0]);
            //Y = Int32.Parse(split_data [1]);

            transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        }
        ));








    }
    // start from unity3d
    public void Start()
    {
        te = GetComponent<TaskExecutorScript> ();
        init();  

        // cube = GameObject.Find ("Cube");
    }

    // OnGUI
    void OnGUI()
    {
        Rect rectObj=new Rect(40,10,200,400);
        GUIStyle style = new GUIStyle();
        style.alignment = TextAnchor.UpperLeft;
        GUI.Box(rectObj,"# UDPReceive\n"+IP+": "+port+" #\n"
                + "shell> nc -u "+IP+": "+port+" \n"
                + "\nLast Packet: \n"+ lastReceivedUDPPacket
                ,style);
    }

    // init
    private void init()
    {
        // Endpunkt definieren, von dem die Nachrichten gesendet werden.
        print("UDPSend.init()");

        // define port
        port = 6666;  

        // status
        print("Sending to "+IP+": "+port);
        print("Test-Sending to this Port: nc -u "+IP+": "+port+"");


        // ----------------------------
        // Abhören
        // ----------------------------
        // Lokalen Endpunkt definieren (wo Nachrichten empfangen werden).
        // Einen neuen Thread für den Empfang eingehender Nachrichten erstellen.
        receiveThread = new Thread(
            new ThreadStart(ReceiveData));
        receiveThread.IsBackground = true;
        receiveThread.Start();

    }

    // receive thread
    private  void ReceiveData()
    {

        client = new UdpClient(port);
        while (true)
        {

            try
            {
                // Bytes empfangen.
                IPEndPoint anyIP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
                byte[] data = client.Receive(ref anyIP);

                // Bytes mit der UTF8-Kodierung in das Textformat kodieren.
                string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);

                // Den abgerufenen Text anzeigen.
                print(">> " + text);

                // latest UDPpacket
                lastReceivedUDPPacket=text;

            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                print(err.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    // getLatestUDPPacket
    // cleans up the rest
    public string getLatestUDPPacket()
    {
        return lastReceivedUDPPacket;
    }
    /*
        public void UseInfo()
        {
            info = lastReceivedUDPPacket;
            arraySplit = info.Split ('0');
            x =  int.Parse(arraySplit [0]);
            y =  int.Parse(arraySplit [1]);
            this.transform.position = new Vector3 (x, y, 0);

        } */

    void OnDisable() 
    { 
        if ( receiveThread!= null) 
            receiveThread.Abort(); 

        client.Close(); 
    } 
}
```

and

```
 using UnityEngine;
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public delegate void Task();

    public class TaskExecutorScript : MonoBehaviour {

        private Queue<Task> TaskQueue = new Queue<Task>();
        private object _queueLock = new object();

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update () {
            lock (_queueLock)
            {
                if (TaskQueue.Count > 0)
                    TaskQueue.Dequeue()();
            }
        }

        public void ScheduleTask(Task newTask)
        {
            lock (_queueLock)
            {
                if (TaskQueue.Count < 100)
                    TaskQueue.Enqueue(newTask);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does `static void Main` doing there? That's not unity code, that's how you start dot net applications... anyway you're using `te` which is an instance variable inside a static method (that weird `Main` method). You're not allowed to do that. A static method is by definition not part of the instance so it doesn't have to access it.